# How to open a website's url from the miniprogram into the (wechat) browser? No nested webview

Tags: wechat-miniprogram

I need to open an url of a website into a browser. It can be, best case, the native browser, or the wechat browser.

I don't want to open the url in a nested webview.

I didn't find any function or button's open-type to do so.

Comment: This can't be done. Best workaround is to help the user copy the url to their clipboard.